# Grandes textos em banco de dados ou apenas um caminho para um arquivo txt(Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

Minha duvida é a seguinte: É melhor colocar quantidades enormes de textos em um banco de dados ou criar um código que trabalhe com um txt á parte?(abrir/salvar/modificar)

Já tenho dito código em PhP e venho utilizando isso para evitar que o banco de dados fique excessivamente grande com conteudo que pode ser alocado em outros lugares.

E bateu a duvida se esta é uma boa prática.

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Quais critérios quer considerar? Qual o seu cenário? Os conteúdos dos arquivos precisam ser indexados ou serão conteúdo de buscas? A sua pergunta precisar ser mais objetiva para que a resposta também seja. Dê uma olhada em [help] e também em [ask] para lhe ajudar a [edit] para o padrão do site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vai depender muito do que você precisa fazer. Um banco de dados pode oferecer vários serviços que podem ser úteis, como indexação do conteúdo do arquivo, backup sincronizado com os demais dados da sua aplicação, controle de acesso / alteração e independência em relação ao caminho/nome do arquivo.
Se nada disso for importante para você, pode deixar fora do banco de dados que, na minha opinião, facilita o desenvolvimento.

(Apenas um comentário: SharePoint, um dos grandes produtos da Microsoft, armazena os documentos todos na base de dados por padrão.)

Answer (score 0):

Se é uma boa prática vai depender da estrutura da sua aplicação,
por exemplo, se você precisa pesquisar conteúdo dentro destes textos, o que ficará complicado para você fazer, apenas com o caminho dos arquivos.

Você pode avaliar um banco de dados como o `MongoDB` (ou outro Banco de dados `NoSQL`) para armazenar estas informações, já que ele lida muito bem com este tipo de dado em quantidades absurdas.